# What's the difference between the queries? "SELECT * FROM bookings where code = null" and "SELECT * FROM bookings where code IS null"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, operators

I get different outputs for these queries. Did anyone face this?

Comment: The `= null` comparison is invalid SQL. Use `is null`.

Answer (score 2):

The `col= null` would not work because

> NULL means I don't know. which is a placeholder to say there is the absence of a value.

`=` evaluate for values, so that will not to work.

You need to use `IS NULL` to get `NULL` row value.

Answer (score 0):

That's completely normal. "X = NULL" is NULL, which amounts to false ("NOT X = NULL" is also false; NULL is falser than false). For most SQL dialects.

Comment: Wrong. In postgres it always evaluates to NULL, not FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

=NULL IS is an expression of a value and IS NULL is the preferred method of evaluating the condition of a variable being NULL.

Here is the detail description
[Click here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/understandingthedifferencebetweenisnull/871/)

Comment: OP using Postgres, not MS SQL. There `IS NULL` is **only** valid method for checking, not preferred as you mentioned.

Comment: Ohhk. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement,
SELECT * FROM bookings where code = null--

> It Checks Directly if any row has the value null

The Second Statement,
SELECT * FROM bookings where code IS null

> It Checks all the rows its a null or not..

Comment: First query does not check on NULL at all.